# How to remove duplicates from excel file while exporting to database spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in a project that has to import and export data from an excel file to database and otherwise. I have to get the data from database and then  .But how to check if this data in excel file are not repeating based on id,phone number,username.
Here is the method to read from excel file

```
@Override
public List<Contact> read(String FilePath) throws IOException {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(FilePath));

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    HSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
            int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                // contact.setId((String) nextRow.getCell(nextCell));
                contact.setId((long) (nextCell.getNumericCellValue()));
                break;

            case 1:
                contact.setFirstName(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 2:
                contact.setLastName(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 3:
                contact.setPhoneNumber(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 4:
                contact.setAddress(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 5:
                contact.setCity(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 6:
                contact.setEmail(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 7:
                contact.setZipCode((int) (nextCell.getNumericCellValue()));
                break;
            }

        }
        contactList.add(contact);
    }

    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();

    return contactList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should overide the equals Method in Contact and do

```
if(!contactList.contains(contact))
{
 contactList.add(contact);
}
```